# Transfer files from an unix server to a windows server using mule

Tags: mule, sftp, anypoint-studio

I need to transfer some files from an Unix server to a windows server using Mulesoft; that is Source: Unix server and target: windows server.
Also I have to archive the files in source Unix directory, once they are processed. 
How can I achive this? Can I use two SFTP connectors? Any direction towards how can I achive this would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing - the target server i. e. the windows server is not exposed to FTP/SFTP. Now how can I transfer the files to that server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Mule question. Mule is note Magic which solves all your problems.

This question is about how to transfer files from Unix to Windows. It is not clear where your Mule runtime working. It could be on Unix since you had mention that Windows target has no FTP or it could be Windows since you tag question with Anypoint-studio.

Assuming your runtime is on Unix. Then question is simple how to transfer file from Unix pushing to Windows. Since your Windows box has no FTP and excluding weird solution like sending email I know only one solution [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) but it requires some knowledge of Unix.

If your runtime is Windows then it's opposite question - how to get files from Unix. Probably Unix already have FTP server or the same Samba can help.

In both cases eventually you will see opposite side as regular file and then you can use File Connector which will do the job including archiving (use move file box to store processed file).

If you have Mule runtime running on both environments which communicate with each other (which I doubt) then one of them (slave, with source so, Unix) could produce HTTP connector to expose files and then another one on Windows, as active (master) one should use HTTP connector to get these files.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I didn't understand your question - "where Mule runtime is  working". I have to deploy the mule app in CloudHub; if this answers your question. We need to have one single mule interface which will connect the unix server with the windows server.

Comment: Even better. You have third server in the cloud which should have access to your Unix server and to Windows server. So it should be way for such third party to get/put files to your servers. For Unix it is usually FTP (if set up). Windows should provide the same. Otherwise your Windows box should share something publicly to the entire internet which is highly not recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. Really helped me understand the concept.

Comment: What do you think about using AS2 connector in mule?